# Gatling processing or formatting feeder data?

Tags: gatling

In gatling how would I read data from a feeder and format it before it's fed to the exec statement? I want something like the following. Where I inject the value of queryData from the feeder but apply the formatData function on the input before passing the string into the get function. T

```
val scn = scenario("QueryRun")
    .repeat(10) {
        feed(queries)
        .exec(http("${queryname}").get("/test?input=" + formatData("${queryData}") ))
        .pause(200 milliseconds)
}
```

he formatted data may not preserve the ${queryData} string so I cannot just return a string from formatData with the queryData parameter in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feeder API provides a convert operation. Please [read the documentation](http://gatling.io/docs/2.0.2/session/feeder.html#converting).